# Не работает окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Я впервые изучаю PyQt вот код ui файла:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(559, 470)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../Всё всё/icon.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 231, 331))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit:focus {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 80, 231, 331))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 151, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 63 13pt \"Yu Gothic UI\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 50, 291, 21))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 63 13pt \"Yu Gothic UI\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 430, 461, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(" QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"    font-size: 15px;\n"
"} \n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: red;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "GUI Program"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите текст стиха"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Здесь после нажатия будет результат"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Анализировать стих"))
```

Вот код main:

```py
import sys
# Импортируем наш интерфейс из файла
from ui import *
from PyQt5 import *

class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QtWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

# Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
# при нажатии на кнопку
def MyFunction(self):
    pass

if __name__=="__name__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В теории просто должно открыться окно которое я сделал, но ничего нет:(
Ошибки в cmd просто напросто нет:/ В чём проблема? Запустите у себя. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Где объявлены `MyWin, Ui_MainWindow`?

Comment: if __name__=="__name__":

Comment: Там исправил на Ui_Dialog. Всё равно не робит

Comment: Что такое MyWin?

Comment: Я смотрю с урока, это было окно с ui.py, уже понял и исправил, но всё равно не робит

Answer (score 1):

У вас сплошные опечатки :)

```
import sys
#from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from ui import *
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(559, 470)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background-color: silver;}")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 231, 331))
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit:focus {background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);}")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 80, 231, 331))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 151, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 63 13pt \"Yu Gothic UI\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 50, 291, 21))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 63 13pt \"Yu Gothic UI\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 430, 461, 31))

        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(" QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"    font-size: 15px;\n"
"} \n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: red;\n"
"}")

        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "GUI Program"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Введите текст стиха"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Здесь после нажатия будет результат"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Анализировать стих"))


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget):          #QMainWindow):                    # +
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()                                              # +
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Здесь прописываем событие нажатия на кнопку
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    # Пока пустая функция которая выполняется
    # при нажатии на кнопку
    def MyFunction(self):
        pass


if __name__=="__main__":                                               # __main__
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Такая ошибка

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов  это что, опишите подробнее.   `pip install PyQt5`

Comment: pip install PyQt5 - устанавливает PyQt версии 5

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов  да `pip install PyQt5`  устанавливает PyQt5

Comment: Я запускаю ваш код и вылетает данная ошибка qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

Comment: как это исправить?

Comment: @МатвейВоронцов почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560515/qt-qpa-plugin-could-not-find-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-in  и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495620/qt-5-1-1-application-failed-to-start-because-platform-plugin-windows-is-missi